# Nested object JSON serialization in WebAPI

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NET 4.0, MVC 4, Web API. I have following data structure:

```
Dictionary<Actor, Int32> TopActorToMovieCount = new Dictionary<Actor, Int32>(10);
```

And following entry in WebApiConfig:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

In my Controller, I am returning `TopActorToMovieCount` this way:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage HighestMovies()
    {            
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, MvcApplication.TopActorToMovieCount);
    }
```

But the JSON output it is giving is:

```
{"api.Models.Actor":137,"api.Models.Actor":125,"api.Models.Actor":99,"api.Models.Actor":96,"api.Models.Actor":83,"api.Models.Actor":82,"api.Models.Actor":81,"api.Models.Actor":79,"....
```

Why it is not giving JSON structure for object of `Actor`?

I am sure that I am missing something, bout couldn't figure out. I tried adding following, but it didn't work:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

PS: When I switch to XML output, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

See similar question here: [Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504245/not-ableto-serialize-dictionary-with-complex-key-using-json-net)

In this case, you are using "Actor" as the Key of your dictionary.  Dictionary stores key/value pairs.  So when creating the JSON response, it interprets the "Actor" as a key which is converted to a string, and the "Int32" as the value thus giving you

`{"api.Models.Actor":137}` or `{key:value}`

because

`Actor.ToString()` would result in `"api.Models.Actor"`

Here's a link to the definition of Dictionary: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But in that case, if I just serialize List<Actor> that should also give me api.Models.Actor, because .toString() will come in picture in this case as well. But serialization of List<Actor> gives me proper result.