# Serialize a Dictionary with an object type key and a List type value into Json

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, json.net

I'd like to convert into Json the following Dictionary type:

```
public class Repsonse
{
    public Dictionary<Employee, List<Car>> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Seniority { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationPlate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expect it to be serialized into the following [Json](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=6498cd40d2cf0c59fe9bf9c163ed68c8):

```
{
  "Dictionary": [
    {
      "Name": "John Doe",
      "Seniority": "2",
      "OwnerId": "1111"
      "Cars": [
          {
            "OwnerId": "1111"
            "Model": "Chevrolet Spark",
            "RegistrationPlate": "LTO1234"
          },
          {
            "OwnerId": "1111"
            "Model": "Chevrolet Malibu",
            "RegistrationPlate": "LTO5678"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Jane Doe",
      "Seniority": "10",
      "OwnerId": "9999"
      "Cars": [
          {
            "OwnerId": "9999"
            "Model": "Mercedes Benz",
            "RegistrationPlate": "ABC1234"
          },
          {
            "OwnerId": "9999"
            "Model": "Mercedes Maybach",
            "RegistrationPlate": "ABC5678"
          }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using NewtonSoft Json for the serialization, and [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504245/not-ableto-serialize-dictionary-with-complex-key-using-json-net/31412665#31412665) that I need to use a `TypeConverter` to enable this kind of serialization, but it doesn't work for me.

Here's the `TypeConverter` implemenetation:

```
public class Employee : TypeConverter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Seniority { get; set; }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return ((Employee)value).Name + "," + ((Employee)value).Id + "," + ((Employee)value).Seniority;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

You can see the full example code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E42qRa).
How can I make it work?

Comment: "doesn't work" how, exactly? What goes wrong?

Comment: The key properties are not serialized. Just its type name. You can see it in the linked fiddle.

Comment: The expected json is going to be hard to get from that dictionary, more appropriate would be a dictionary serialization as you seem to allude to in your code example, like `"Smith, John": { cars }, "Anderson, Mr.": { cars }`. You're better off making Cars a property of Employee if you want that JSON

Answer (score 1):

The json output format that you have is for list not for dictionary. If you want to use dictionary may be you can follow below one

JSON Response

```
{
 "Dictionary": {
  "John Doe": {
   "Name": "John Doe",
   "Id": "1111",
   "Seniority": 2,
   "Cars": [
     {
       "OwnerId": "1111",
       "Model": "Chevrolet Spark",
       "RegistrationPlate": "LTO1234"
     },
     {
       "OwnerId": "1111",
       "Model": "Chevrolet Malibu",
       "RegistrationPlate": "LTO5678"
     }
   ]
 },
 "Jane Doe": {
   "Name": "Jane Doe",
   "Id": "9999",
   "Seniority": 10,
   "Cars": [
     {
       "OwnerId": "9999",
       "Model": "Mercedes Benz",
       "RegistrationPlate": "ABC1234"
     },
     {
       "OwnerId": "9999",
       "Model": "Mercedes Maybach",
       "RegistrationPlate": "ABC5678"
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

and code will be

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        Response res = new Response { Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Employee>() };

        Employee firstEmployee = new Employee { Name = "John Doe", Id = "1111", Seniority = 2 };
        Employee secondEmployee = new Employee { Name = "Jane Doe", Id = "9999", Seniority = 10 };
        firstEmployee.Cars.Add(new Car { OwnerId = "1111", Model = "Chevrolet Spark", RegistrationPlate = "LTO1234" });
        firstEmployee.Cars.Add(new Car { OwnerId = "1111", Model = "Chevrolet Malibu", RegistrationPlate = "LTO5678" });

        secondEmployee.Cars.Add(new Car { OwnerId = "9999", Model = "Mercedes Benz", RegistrationPlate = "ABC1234" });
        secondEmployee.Cars.Add(new Car { OwnerId = "9999", Model = "Mercedes Maybach", RegistrationPlate = "ABC5678" });

        res.Dictionary.Add(firstEmployee.Name, firstEmployee);
        res.Dictionary.Add(secondEmployee.Name, secondEmployee);

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
        Console.WriteLine(result);

    }
}

public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Employee> Dictionary { get; set; }

    public class Employee : TypeConverter
    {
        public Employee(string name, decimal seniority, string id, List<Car> cars)
        {
            Name = name;
            Seniority = seniority;
            Id = id;
            Cars = cars;
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }
        public Employee()
        {
            Cars = new List<Car>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Seniority { get; set; }
        public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return ((Employee)value).Name + "," + ((Employee)value).Id + "," + ((Employee)value).Seniority;
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string RegistrationPlate { get; set; }
    }

}
```