# How to serialize dictionary<object,object> to json

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, elasticsearch, nest

I have:

1)

```
Dictionary<MyClass, double>
```

2) elasticsearch 7

3) nest 7

I want to write my dictionary in elasticsearch database by:

```
client.IndexDocument(myDictionary).
```

I know, I can use

```
List<KeyValuePair<MyClass, double>>
```

But in my work I need use Dictionary.

Comment: A dictionary *is* an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>. It should be no different than what you already have. Have you tried something, did you get an error? What do you mean `elasicsearch json` ? JSON is just one standard, there are no variations by product

Comment: Are you trying to serialize your data as an *array* instead of a single object? Or index multiple documents instead of a single one? In JavaScript/JSON, an object *is* a dictionary. If you want the result to be serialized as an array, don't use a `Dictionary<>` directly. Perhaps you can cast the dictionary to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<>>` and pass it to `IndexDocument`. If the client uses reflection though, it could still serialize it as an object. In that case you could use `ToArray()` or `ToList()` to convert the dictionary to a list

Comment: A dictionary in json has to be `string -> value`, where `value` can be any legal json construct, literal values, objects, lists. The key, however, has to be a string. So you will have to turn your `MyClass` objects into strings in order to serialize them as keys for a dictionary. Are you trying to produce json that fits a particular schema? is that why you're mentioning elastisearch or nest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a type converter eg.`MyClassConverter` for `MyClass` and then add the attribute `[TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))]` to the MyClass class declaration. This means that, instead of using the default ToString(), it will use the type convert that you define to serialize as you want.

The link ["How to: Implement a Type Converter"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) shows how to create a type converter.

The SO link showing the answer is:
[Not ableTo Serialize Dictionary with Complex key using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504245/not-ableto-serialize-dictionary-with-complex-key-using-json-net)